# Limiting an XPath predicate: predicate starting with 

Tags: xpath, openxml

I am navigating this office open xml file using XPath **1.0** (extract):

```
<sheetData ref="A1:XFD108">
    <row spans="1:3" r="1">
        <c t="s" r="A1">
            <is>
                <t>FirstCell</t>
            </is>
        </c>
        <c t="s" r="C1">
            <is>
                <t>SecondCell</t>
            </is>
        </c>
    </row>
    <row spans="1:3" r="2">
        <c t="s" r="A2">
            <is>
                <t>ThirdCell</t>
            </is>
        </c>
        <c t="s" r="C2">
            <is>
                <t>[persons.ID]</t>
            </is>
        </c>
    </row>
</sheetData>
```

I need to find the cell that says "[persons.ID]", which is a variable. Technically, I need to find the first `<row>` containing a `descendant::t` that starts with `[` and closes with `]`. I currently have:

```
.//row//t[starts-with(text(), '[') and 
substring(text(), string-length(text())) = ']']/ancestor::row
```

So I filter and then go up again. It works, but I'd like to understand XPath better here - I found no way filter the predicate. Can you point me to a valid equivalent of doing something like `.//row[descendant::t[starts-with()...]]`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Technically, I need to find the first
>    containing a descendant::t that
>   starts with `[` and closes with `]`.

```
/sheetData/row[c/is/t[starts-with(.,'[')]
                     [substring(.,string-length(.))=']']]
              [1]
```

or

```
/sheetData/row[.//t[starts-with(.,'[') and
                    substring(.,string-length(.))=']']][1]
```

or

```
(//row[.//t[starts-with(.,'[') and
            substring(.,string-length(.))=']']])[1]
```

Comment: 3) is exactly what I was looking for - I didn't know I could nest predicates, and the . operator still puzzles me as well sometimes :-) Thank you.

Comment: @PeerBr: You are wellcome. Also, do note that last expression hasn't the best performance (starting `//` operator, forcing expression evaluation first with `()` maybe loosing optimization). If you know your input schema, you should go with the first expression.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
.//row[starts-with(descendant::t/text(),'[') and substring(descendant::t/text(), string-length(descendant::t/text())) = ']' ]
```

This will give you the row, however one significant problem could be if your `row` has two `t` elements that would satisfy different conditions, but not both conditions. e.g. one `t` starts with [, and another ends with ]

Obvsiously, what you have doesn't have this problem

Another option: use translate

```
.//row[translate(descendant::t/text(),"0123456789","") = "[]"]
```

That will strip the numeric characters and then it's a simple comparison to the [] characters

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the potential issue for the first option.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the potential issue for the first option. However, when testing the first option even with a subset of your solution (.//row[starts-with(descendant::t/text(),'[')]), I get a "too many items" error in XMLSpy and no results in my prog. Probably because there can be >1 descendant::t? Regarding the second option, I think that's ok if the within [] are integers, but they are in practice [a-zA-Z0-9\.] and could possibly be any char, so I think that's not suited to my particular problem.

Comment: @PeerBr: you *could* add the additional character possibilities to the 2nd parameter of translate though that could, obviously, get quite large.